# Get lookup from REST API

Tags: rest, lookup-column

REST API url is

```
/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?&$top=100
```

I have a lookup column called `Sector` in the list. How to retrieve this lookup value from the success call of ajax from the given url? Is it possible to retrieve the lookup value without using `$expand`?

Comment: When we query an OData entity or collection, the default response does not include related entities. We need to use $expand option in the query string of the request.

Comment: You can expand just the value you need if you are worried about response size. Example: '$expand=Category/Title'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible  to retrieve the lookup value without using `$expand`!! In that case you can consider **JSOM**.

```
spListItem.get_item('{Column Name}').get_lookupValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

Without using `$expand` it's not possible to get `lookupValue` in REST API.

But hopefully you will get `lookupId` using REST API by selecting `SectorId`
`/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=SectorId&$top=100`

Otherwise you need to go with JSOM only.